# Why we use lazy loading and is it necessary to use it in small projects like SPA?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know why we use lazy loading and is it necessary to use lazy loading in small projects like SPA?

Comment: One uses lazy loading when lazy loading is appropriate

Comment: Apart from what @JaromandaX said above, this question is likely opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

> The average time it takes to fully load the average mobile landing page is 22 seconds. However, research also indicates 53% of people will leave a mobile page if it takes longer than 3 seconds to load.

[~ Google (PDF)](https://think.storage.googleapis.com/docs/mobile-page-speed-new-industry-benchmarks.pdf)

What really matters in Web development these days is TTI (Time to interaction), so basically how long it takes until the user can interact with the UI.

Through lazy loading, you can load additional gimicks (images, some fancy JS script for animations) *after* the page was loaded, therefore reducing the TTI greatly.

> is it necessary to use lazy loading in small projects like SPA?

Load time is always a feature, no matter how large the page is. Just "lazy loading everything" however won't help you at all, as some JavaScripts are mandatory for your page to be usable (especially for SPAs).

Some ressources:

[Nick Craver - Optimization considerations](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2015/03/24/optimization-considerations/)

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading avoids downloading the whole spa application in one big bundle. Instead of it will be downloaded in chunks. It helps you to decrease the startup time of your app.

I wouldn't say that SPAs are usualy small projects. They often grow very fast with new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For example, an LDAP server has 1 trillion data on employee all across the globe. If you don't use lazy loading, it will take a lot of time to load the data. When you just want to take a look at certain information, not the whole, the lazy loading really comes in handy.

It's just an example. On your browser, you will see 5 organization ( that has 1 trillion data), when you click one organization of that, it will lazyload and show some branches of those data. When you click one particular branch, you will see departments of that(say it's like American branch, African branch of a corporate company), and so on. Thus, lazyloading can not only save time but can take away the heavy load on the system.